# Continuous time (hours in decimals) interacting with a categorical variable

Tags: categorical-data, interaction, continuous-data

Apologies for the stupid question, but I appreciate any comment or suggestion.

I have a dataset xdata, describing the frequency of the response variable X (behaviour - continuous) for 15 individuals (ID). I want to test the effect of 3 categorical conditions (A, B, C) and the interaction with Time in which we collected data (so, also continuous) to test if the changes in behaviour are due to the different conditions or are simply due to general daily behavior changes unrelated to these conditions. The dataset goes like this:

```
ID  Session  Time (hours in decimals)   Condition   Freq

a   520          10.53                      A       0.53

a   600          11.43                      A       0.11


a   530          9.56                       B       0.06

a   600          10.00                      C       0.33

b   534          12.50                      A       0.54    

(… 3464 observations of 15 individuals)
```

I would like to fit a linear mixed effect model in R, from the lm4 package (glmer() function):
model<-glmer(X~condition*Time+(1|ID), weights = Session, family=binomial, data= xdata)

I am not even sure if this is possible to fit (asking for a reviewer), with the continuous variable time as it is. I am missing something. Should I transform it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed possible but you should be careful about the syntax in the formula regarding the effects you want to include in your analysis.

In R's syntax, if you write `var1*var2`, the resulting model will include both main effects of `var1` and `var2` as well as the effect of their interaction.

However, if you only want to include the interaction term (remove the main effects), you should instead write `var1:var2`

Based on what you wrote

> I want to test the effect of 3 categorical conditions (A, B, C) and the interaction with Time

it seems that you want to include the main effect of the variable `condition` plus the effects of its interaction with `Time`. Thus (from what I understand) you don't want to include the main effect of `Time`.

To do so you can simply write `condition + condition:time`

See this [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40730731/11293734) on Stackoverflow about the syntax of R's formula.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is already a great step! However, the model still fails to converge because of very large eigenvalue, a warning says. Should I transform time?

Comment: @RaquelCosta You can try to transform the variable time, in which case you'll to adjust the interpretation of the coefficients to this modification.

Comment: I understand. The problem is that some conditions happen only in the morning and some in the afternoon. I wonder if I should include time as random effect instead (turning into categories of each half an hour or one hour), since the aim is to test the changes comparing the conditions. However, to do that, I need to transform time to categorical (say, intervals of 30 mints). When running the model, everything is way to significant. What I did try was to have the random (Period:Time), being Time continuous, but I think I miss the point here